# multiple glTF files sharing the same textures

Tags: export, file-format, gltf

My question is about if there are export settings that will prevent duplicate texture maps when I import them into a game engine because glB files typically pack the textures into the file.

Outside of the game engine, this looks especially silly when an smaller level of detail(LOD) version of the model(5000 tris) is similar in size to the high poly version(60,000 tris) because they are packing the same textures.

Thank you.

Comment: On the glTF export dialog, have you tried picking "Format: glTF Separate"?  It should keep the textures separate.  Beware it may overwrite images in certain circumstances, so I would save the glTF file(s) to a folder that's separate from the Blender project and source images.

Comment: This is the solution I'm looking for. Thank you.